# How can I create a Google document in a folder?

Tags: google-drive

I organize my Google Docs into folders.

When I want to create a new document in a folder, I have to:

- create the document
- save it
- go back to view all
- click the check box for that file
- click Folders
- click the Folder I want to move my document to
- click "Apply Changes"

**How can I just create a document in the folder, as you do in Windows Explorer for instance?**

Comment: Especially interesting because you can right click in the document area of a folder, go to New → Document but it's still created without a label. (To reduce your clicks, you can also drag & drop.)

Comment: Looks like right clicking in document area of folder no longer works, unless right clicking on a document itself.

Comment: "Folders" are now "Collections" and you can see how to create documents directly in a collection here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-doc-directly-inside-a-collection

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the answer is that there is currently no way to do this.  Multiple forum posts exist on the subject (e.g. Google Docs help forums), it seems to be a widely requested feature, but Google has yet to implement it.

**Update:**

The comment below was wrong when it was posted, but as of checking today looks like this has been fixed. When browsing a label, clicking on the Create New button on the top left now creates the new document with the label currently being browsed.

Comment: May have been true back then but it appears to work now.

Comment: Just tested this: navigated to a folder, right clicked, New -> Document.  The new document is not created within the folder (or label really).  A far as I can tell, this is still not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Click *Create New->Folder* (upper right hand corner) and wha-la:  A new folder you can drag your documents into.

Note however that it is a bit confusing because the default selected (and I use the term loosely) folder is "All Items", thus if you drag a document to a folder it does actually move there, but it doesn't disappear from the list.

Also note that you cannot drag and drop documents into your Google Chrome bookmarks.

Comment: Let me know if my answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit easier, you can drag and drop the document to the folder

Comment: yes, I do this 2-step process but since google docs is otherwise so user friendly (e.g. you can put commas and slashes in file names), I would just think there is a way to create a file in a folder that already exists without this extra step, like you can in Explorer or any other file management GUI e.g. on Mac or Ubuntu, it just seems standard, odd they don't enable this basic feature somehow.